# Why does this C code appear to hang sometimes?

Tags: c

I'm trying to recreate the `bitset` class from C++ in C, as a small experiment. The idea behind this code is to have a struct with a flexible array member as the container for the bits, which will be represented by unsigned integers.

I feel like I'm probably using flexible array members wrong, and that's what's causing the issue, but that could be wrong.

When I run the code below, it will sometimes print and terminate immediately, and sometimes hang for up to a minute before terminating. While it's hanging, the terminal won't respond to any user input.

Compiling with GCC on Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct bitset {
    int size;  // Number of bits
    unsigned int data[];
} bitset;

bitset* bitset_init(int init_size) {
    bitset* bs =
        malloc(sizeof(bitset) + sizeof((init_size + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) /
                                       sizeof(unsigned int)));
    bs->size = init_size;

    // Initialise bits to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < (init_size + 7) / 8; i++) {
        bs->data[i] = 0;
    }
    return bs;
};

int main() {
    bitset* x = bitset_init(45);
    printf("%d", x->data[0]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Buffer overflow and undefined behavior. https://godbolt.org/z/nn3Yjhe5h

Comment: It looks like you need to read about the [`sizeof`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sizeof-operator-c/) operator in depth. This looks wrong `sizeof((init_size + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1)`

Comment: Maybe time to use `calloc`, it helps clarify your thinking.

Comment: @tadman I don't think `calloc()` is appropriate for allocating a struct with a FAM. It's for allocating arrays.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but I mean there's a pretty major failure here with the division.

Comment: @tadman Agreed, but they can't switch to `calloc()` to fix it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate the correct amount of bytes, you are doing it wrong as your second `sizeof` which is nested with another `sizeof` is returning the size of `size_t` (not 100% sure that it is `size_t` but highly likely) or possibly `sizeof(int)` which leads to the same problem.

Instead of

```
malloc(sizeof(bitset) + sizeof((init_size + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) /
                                       sizeof(unsigned int)));
```

You have to do something like

```
malloc(sizeof(bitset) + init_size * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

But guessing from the for loop you might want to have something like

```
malloc(sizeof(bitset) + number_of_bits * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

The problem with your code has to do with the fact that you are writing past the end of the flexible array member (*overflow*) causing with this **undefined behavior**. Which explains what you observed.

Additional Note:

Looking at this

```
sizeof((init_size + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) / sizeof(unsigned int))
```

it lloks like you are trying to actually use

```
(init_size + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) / sizeof(unsigned int)
```

Which still would be wrong. If you want 1 byte per bit, you have to multiply the number of bits by `sizeof(<whatever the type of the bit is>)`

Comment: The very last code block and the line at the bottom is what kicked my brain into gear, thank you for the assistance. I probably wasn't quite as clear in the question as I could have been. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing a little too much in your `malloc`. You should just be able to simple do:

```c
bitset* bs = malloc(sizeof *bs + (sizeof(unsigned int) * size));
```

For your loop where you are initializing everything to 0, the compiler will likely replace that loop with a `memset` or even a `calloc` if it pleases. So, instead of the loop, you can `#include <string.h>` and do this:

```c
memset(bs->data, 0, size);
```